# How do I specify that my app only supports iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, device

I'm really confused by the parameters I need to place in my plist file. I want to support only iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s. I don't want to support any other iPhone models, iPads or iPod Touch.

What settings do I need?

Comment: What specific feature are you after? You can try setting UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: It's as simple as requiring `telephony` and `front-facing-camera` in UIRequiredDeviceCapability, however, I'm not sure how this would go over at Apple HQ when it comes time to submit...

Comment: I've used the front-facing-camera as a requirement when I wanted to limit the supported devices, and although my app didn't use camera it was approved by Apple without problems.

Comment: @Pauldelange It's a performance thing. Can just about get it smooth on a 4, but no chance with a 3s.

Comment: @petersarnowski thanks. A forward facing camera is vital to my app, so this sounds like the way to go. Wonder why there is no explicit way to target specific devices.

Comment: @1ndivisible I guess Apple sees no reason in restricting apps from devices that can run them. And a word of warning - I once did that (limit an app to just iPhone 4 for performance issues) and got a ton of angry feedback from people who wanted the app anyway.

Comment: @petersarnowski Problem is the 3GS is way too long in the tooth for my app. It's just too slow. I'd rather not offer an app that is laggy and probably crashes due to low memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some key- values in information plist which are available in iPhone 4 or higher version -

Like -

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>gyroscope</string>
    </array>
```

You can check about information plist from - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: Thanks. I understand the mechanics of setting values with the application plist. However there is no way as far as I can see of explicitly limiting device support.